# Various Screens Response based on screen width

Tags: angular

I am using a grid layout where I want the text responsive to viewports.  I am using this [article](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) and style :

```
font-size: calc(16px + 0.5vw);
```

How may I implement this with my ts and html files?  Here is the ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface Tile {
  color: string;
  cols: number;
  rows: number;
  text: string;
  fontSize: string;
  fontFamily: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'grid-list-dynamic-example',
  templateUrl: 'grid-list-dynamic-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['grid-list-dynamic-example.css'],
})
export class GridListDynamicExample {
  tiles: Tile[] = [

    { text: 'One', cols: 5, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue', fontSize: '20', 
fontFamily: 'Rubik'},
    { text: 'Two', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: 'lightgreen', fontSize: '20', 
fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed'},
    { text: 'Three', cols: 2, rows: 2, color: 'lightpink', fontSize: 
'25', fontFamily:  'Rubik'  },
    { text: 'Four', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1', fontSize: '30' , 
fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed' },
    { text: 'Five', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1', fontSize: '35', 
fontFamily:  'Roboto Condensed'},
    { text: 'Six', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1', fontSize: 
'40',fontFamily: 'Rubik' },
  ];
}
```

This is the html file:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="20vh" [gutterSize]="'0px'">
  <mat-grid-tile
      *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
      [colspan]="tile.cols"
      [rowspan]="tile.rows"
      [style.background]="tile.color"
      [ngStyle]="{'font-size': calc(tile.fontSize + 'px' + 0.5vw);, 
'font-family': tile.fontFamily +', sans-serif;'}"
   >
    {{tile.text}}
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

I get an error on this line:  [ngStyle]="{'font-size': calc(tile.fontSize + 'px' + 0.5vw);,

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sse4n5-stnfm8)

Comment: any reason why not to use straight CSS?

Comment: Are your brackets & parenthesis opened and closed? The error says you may be missing something

Comment: @jcuypers it is easier to not use a css file for me.

Comment: the larger your app grows /  larger use  change detection / performance will get killed by such statements for trivial css tasks.  but ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is not valid. It should be

```
[ngStyle]="{'font-size': 'calc(' + tile.fontSize + 'px + 0.5vw)', 'font-family': tile.fontFamily +', sans-serif'}"
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sse4n5-vivgf2?file=app%2Fgrid-list-dynamic-example.html)